# How to pass context to Intent in android library?

Tags: java, android

I created a library for the recurrent screen in android and when I tried to implement it in my activity I got this error message.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context android.app.Activity.getApplicationContext()' on a null object reference
        at com.expert.recur.ScreenReco.<init>(ScreenReco.java:15)
        at com.expert.recurringscreen.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:18)
```

My code.
MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ScreenReco screenReco;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        screenReco=new ScreenReco(MainActivity.this);//line 18
        screenReco.value = 1000;
        screenReco.runnable.run();

    }
}
```

My library:

```
public class ScreenReco {
    Activity activity;

    public ScreenReco(Activity activity) {
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    public Context context = activity.getApplicationContext();//line 15
    public int value;
    public Handler handler = new Handler();
    public Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Intent i = new Intent(context, context.getClass());
            handler.postDelayed((Runnable) context,value);
            context.startActivity(i);
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
 'android.content.Context android.app.Activity.getApplicationContext()'
 on a null object reference
```

You can create a [**`Constructor`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/reflect/Constructor).

> A constructor is a special method that is called whenever an object is
>   created using the new keyword.

```
public class ScreenReco {
Activity activity;     

     ScreenReco(Activity ctx)
     {
       this.activity=ctx
     }

}
```

Then

```
ScreenReco screenReco=new ScreenReco(MainActivity.this);
```

Or

```
      @Override
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
      screenReco=new ScreenReco(MainActivity.this);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are supposed to create an object of **ScreenReco** class before assigning values to its variables ...

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ScreenReco screenReco;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
      screenReco=new ScreenReco(); // you are missing this
      screenReco.context = this;
      screenReco.value = 1000;
      screenReco.runnable.run();
  }

}
```

But I strongly recommend you to use constructors for this ... it's the good practice

Answer (score 0):

Your `MainActivity` is almost fine. But, it is not recommended to call `run();` method of `Runnable` object ourself. Instead, pass the `Runnable` object in a constructor of a `Thread` object and call `start();` method on the `Thread` object and let the system call the `run();` method itself when it is appropriate. Your improved `MainActivity` may look like this :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ScreenReco screenReco;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        screenReco=new ScreenReco(MainActivity.this, 1000);//line 18
        // screenReco.value = 1000;
        // if you want to run `runnable` in a new Thread
        // new Thread(screenReco.runnable).start();

        //or if you want to run it in the same thread
        //new Handler().post(screenReco.runnable);

        //screenReco.runnable.run();

    }
}
```

Now moving into your library file i.e. `ScreenReco.java`, it looks like `activity` variable hasn't been initialized while you are trying to call `getApplicationContext()` method in the class as @PraveenSP's answer has already said. A better practice would be **declare all required class variable at once and then initialize them all in the class constructor** as:

```
public class ScreenReco {
    // if you need this activity variable to just use as context
    // then do not use this variable here just use context only
    Activity activity;
    // the better practice here is to declare these variable as private 
    // and pass values for these variables in constructor and initialize them there 
    public Context context;
    public int value;
    public Handler handler;
    public Runnable runnable;

    // constructor improved from your code
    public ScreenReco(Activity activity, int value) {
        this.activity = activity;// this only if you are using activity
        // object to something otherwise get rid of this variable.
        this.context = activity.getApplicationContext();
        this.handler = new Handler();
        this.value = value;
        this.runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Intent i = new Intent(context, context.getClass());
            // handler.postDelayed((Runnable)context, value); 
            context.startActivity(i);
        }
        // this is the edit you need 
        this.handler.postDelayed(runnable, value);
    };
    }

   // this version of constructor is what exactly I would have done by declaring class variable as `private` up there 
   // public ScreenReco(Context context, int value) {
        // this.activity = activity;
        // this.context = context;
        // this.handler = new Handler();
        // also initialize `value` and `runnable` object here
        // this.value = value;
        // this.runnable = new Runnable() {
        // @Override
        // public void run() {
            // Intent i = new Intent(context, context.getClass());
            // handler.postDelayed((Runnable) context,value);
            // context.startActivity(i);
        // }
    // };
    // }
}
```

Also, I'm so **confused** by the code you wrote inside the `runnable`'s `run()` method. It looks like you are trying to start the `MainActivity` from `MainActivity`. And, in the line below, you tried to cast `context` variable to `Runnable` which is very error-prone.

Comment: Yes I wanted my MainActivity to be a recurrent activity thats the reason for calling MainActivity from MainActivity. And it gives me an error if don't cast context to runnable.

Comment: If so, you might wanna use `recreate()` method from your `MainActivity` class. If you want to recreate after say `x` milliseconds, you can write this line of code :  
    `new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    recreate();
                }
            }, x);`

Comment: Thanks. But I'm facing error in run() method, rest everything works fine.

Comment: android.app.Application cannot be cast to java.lang.Runnable at handler.postDelayed((Runnable) context,value);

Comment: yeah, they are incompatible so you cannot cast application object to runnable. Better, you should not use the library at all and use the code in my comment to achieve the same objective.

Comment: @NaveenRM see my further edited answer. I think that will work but thats too much of unnecessary stuff already. But still if you want to work that way, you can.